# Right curly brace of specified height, with the lower tip exactly on baseline

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, tex-core

I need right curly brace of specified height, with the lower tip on the baseline.

I need this in LaTeX, but problems with my attempts can be illustrated better in plain TeX.

Below I have macro `\myrightbraceofheight` which is *intended<sup>*</sup>* to produce such brace. (I have left defaults with second `\hrule` so you can see baseline.)

*<sup>*</sup>*It is intended but it does not.

Two problems:

1. braces are a bit too high.
   I thought I can handle this in LaTeX by graphicx-package's
   `\resizebox*{\width}{<desired height>}{\myrightbraceofheight{<desired height>}}`.
   But I can't. Because of problem 2:
2. The lower tip of the brace is not in all cases at the baseline.

How can I ensure the lower tip of the brace in all cases being at the baseline?

The small vertical gap between baseline and lower tip of brace - is it from some glue? Is it from the font metrics of the glyphs used by TeX for making the brace?

```
\def\myrightbraceofheight#1{%
    \vbox{\topskip=0pt \offinterlineskip %<- this not necessary but who knows?
    \hrule height 0pt depth 0pt
    \hbox{\topskip=0pt \offinterlineskip %<- this not necessary but who knows?
      $\left.\vbox{\topskip=0pt \offinterlineskip %<- this not necessary but who knows?
        \hrule height .5\dimexpr#1\relax depth .5\dimexpr#1\relax 
      }\right\}$%
    }%
    \hrule% height 0pt depth 0pt
    }%
}%

A \myrightbraceofheight{5cm}

B \myrightbraceofheight{2cm}

C \myrightbraceofheight{1cm}

D \myrightbraceofheight{2mm}

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Why opening a new account?

Comment: TeX expects that there will always be at least `\normallineskip` between adjacent lines; this is preset to 1pt.  That is at least part of what is responsible for the gap.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer right now, but you want to set `\delimitershortfall=0pt`, otherwise the delimiters will always be a bit smaller than the rule and therefore will not reach the bottom of the box.

Comment: it should be noted that the height and depth or a character do not necessarily match the visible shape.  \raisebox can even set the height and depth of anything to arbitrary values.

Comment: @egreg I post as guest. I never opened account.

Answer (score 4):

It's essentially impossible to get a delimiter of the *precise* height, because TeX either uses existing glyphs or joins pieces, but this only works for a discrete set of lengths. It has the parameters `\delimiterfactor` and `\delimitershortfall` to somewhat control the tolerance to the specified length.

If you want a delimiter 5cm high, you need to use `\left` and `\right` with a box that extends 2.5cm *above the formula axis*, whose position is `\fontdimen22\textfont2` above the baseline. See the last double dangerous bend on page 152 of the TeXbook.

If you set `\delimiterfactor=1000` and `\delimitershortfall=0pt`, then the delimiter will be *at least* as high as the specified length, but it will be usually higher. With the standard plain TeX (and LaTeX) values `\delimiterfactor=901` and `\delimitershortfall=5pt`, the delimiter will be at least 0.901*5cm and at least 5cm – 5pt (so usually shorter).

```tex
\def\myrightbraceofheight#1{%
  \vbox{
    \delimiterfactor=1000
    \delimitershortfall=0pt
    \hbox{%
      $\mathsurround=0pt % start math mode
      \kern-\nulldelimiterspace % remove the space introduced by \left.
      \left.
      \vbox to0.5\dimexpr#1+2\fontdimen22\textfont2{}
      \right\}
      $% end math mode
    }%
    \hrule height 0pt % set the reference point at the bottom
  }%
}

\leavevmode\rlap{\vrule height 0pt depth 0.1pt width 3cm}% to show the baseline
\vrule height 5cm depth 0pt\myrightbraceofheight{5cm}
\vrule height 2cm depth 0pt\myrightbraceofheight{2cm}

\bye
```

[image]

The same with the standard values for the parameters

[image]

By the way, `\topskip` is *never* used in a `\vbox` and of course setting it in an `\hbox` has no effect. Since TeX never adds interline glue around an `\hrule`, also `\offinterlineskip` is not needed.

You don't need to set contents of a `\vbox` with the `to` specifier, so it's easier `\vbox to` than `\vbox{\hrule...}`.